# Elastic Search Common Documents Query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have the following documents in elastic search:

```
[{
    "_version": 1,
    "uid": "blt275162870bd76359",
    "title": "Entry1",
    "publish_details": [{
            "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff66",
            "locale": "en-us",
            "time": "2020-06-27T11:58:17.699Z",
            "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d"
        },
        {
            "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff66",
            "locale": "hi-in",
            "time": "2020-06-27T11:58:17.699Z",
            "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_version": 1,
    "title": "Entry12",
    "uid": "blt275162870bd76359",
    "publish_details": [{
        "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff66",
        "locale": "mr-in",
        "time": "2020-06-27T11:58:17.699Z",
        "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d"
    }, {
        "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff67",
        "locale": "mr-in",
        "time": "2020-06-27T11:58:17.699Z",
        "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d"
    }]
},
{
    "_version": 1,
    "uid": "blt275162870bd763523",
    "title": "Entry100",
    "publish_details": [{
            "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff66",
            "locale": "en-us",
            "time": "2020-06-27T11:58:17.699Z",
            "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d"
        },
        {
            "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff66",
            "locale": "hi-in",
            "time": "2020-06-27T11:58:17.699Z",
            "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d"
        }, {
            "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff66",
            "locale": "mr-in",
            "time": "2020-06-27T11:58:17.699Z",
            "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_version": 1,
    "title": "Entry18",
    "uid": "blt275162870bd76355",
    "publish_details": [{
        "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff66",
        "locale": "en-us",
        "time": "2020-06-27T11:58:17.699Z",
        "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d"
    }]
},
{
    "_version": 1,
    "title": "Entry16",
    "uid": "blt275162870bd76354",
    "publish_details": []
},
{
    "_version": 1,
    "title": "Entry20",
    "uid": "blt275162870bd76353",
    "publish_details": [{
        "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff66",
        "locale": "en-us",
        "time": "2020-06-27T11:58:17.699Z",
        "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d"
    }]
}]
```

and I want the following response:

```
[{
    "uid": "blt275162870bd76359"
},{


"uid": "blt275162870bd763523"

}]
```

Kindly help me here to create a query for this? publish_details has nested datatype. I want that document whose  publish_details.locale is hi-in.mr-in and en-us and publish_details.environment is blt603fe91adbdcff66 and with uid check. the reason here is uid  blt275162870bd76359 is repeated twice.

Comment: What exact version of Elasticsearch 1.x are you using?

Comment: @Suraj Dalvi according to your question, can u please explain what do u mean by **I want that document whose publish_details.locale is hi-in.mr-in and en-us**

Comment: there is a locale key present in publish_details. so I have here that document whose locale having a value hi-in,mr-in, and en-us with environment condition .but if see uid of first two documents(blt275162870bd76359) is same. and if you combine publish_details of first two documents then it is a combination of hi-in,mr-in, and en-us with the environment: blt603fe91adbdcff66 also for uid: blt275162870bd763523 has everything. @Bhavya

Comment: I am using elasticsearch  version 6.5.4 @Harshit

Comment: Also, I have millions of documents in the index. so the result may be consists of thousands or millions of uid but I want whole uid result in a single query without batching. kindly help me here?

Comment: is any solution for this?

Comment: is any way to get the result? you can refer: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elastic-search-common-documents-query/239426